# Filter array of objects

Tags: javascript, object

I get an array of objects from a MongoDB through API.

I then need to filter the result furthermore (client side).

I'll work with long lists (could be some thousand of results), each object has about 10 properties with some arrays in it.

Example of an object:

```
{
  _id: xxxxxxx,
  foo: [
    { a: "b", c: "d" },
    { a: "b", c: "d" }    
  ],
  data: {
    a: "b",
    c: "d"
  }
}
```

I loop the array async to improve speed:

```
async.filter(documents, function(value) {
  // Search inside the object to check if it contains the given "value"
}, function(results) {
  // Will do something with the result array
});
```

How can I search inside the current object to check if it contains the given value without know in which property I'll find the value?

Comment: Lets say the value you are looking for is `d`, what would be the expected output?

Comment: true or false, depending if the value is present or not

Answer (score 0):

Though I've not included the `async` part but I believe overall searching approach could be like this:

```js
// Input Array
var inpArr = [{
  id: 1,
  foo: [{
    a: "dog",
    b: "cat"
  }]
}, {
  id: 2,
  foo: [{
    a: "kutta",
    b: "billi"
  }]
}];


var myFilter = function(val, item, index, array) {

  var searchResult = scanProperties(item, val);
  return searchResult;
};


// Note: pass additional argument to default filter.
// using Function.Prototype.Bind
var filterResult = inpArr.filter(myFilter.bind(null, "dog"));

alert(filterResult);
console.log(filterResult);

// Recursively scan all properties
function scanProperties(obj, val) {

  var result = false;
  for (var property in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(property) && obj[property] != null) {
      if (obj[property].constructor == Object) {
        result = result || scanProperties(obj[property], val);
      } else if (obj[property].constructor == Array) {
        for (var i = 0; i < obj[property].length; i++) {
          result = result || scanProperties(obj[property][i], val);
        }
      } else {
        result = result || (obj[property] == val);
      }
    }
  }
  return result;
};
```

### JS Fiddle [Searching an Array of Objects](http://jsfiddle.net/rohitkandhal/ga4supdy/)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply iterate through each and every item recursively, like this

```
var data = {
    _id: 1243,
    foo: [{
        a: "b",
        c: "d"
    }, {
        a: "b",
        c: "d"
    }],
    data: {
        a: "b",
        c: "d"
    }
};

function findValue(value) {
    function findItems(document) {
        var type = Object.prototype.toString.call(document);
        if (type.indexOf("Array") + 1) {
            return document.some(findItems);
        } else if (type.indexOf("Object") + 1) {
            return Object.keys(document).some(function(key) {
                return findItems(document[key]);
            });
        } else {
            return document === value;
        }
    }
    return findItems;
}
console.log(findValue('dd')(data));
# false
console.log(findValue('d')(data));
# true
```